# min max using validation

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need t to validate min and max. 
Below is what i was trying but no luck. Please help.

^(?=30)((\d+(.\d*)?)|(.\d+))$

Answer (score 2):

Why use regex for this task. If you have the value in TextBox1.

```
int p = 0;

decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out p);

if(p < 30)
{
   //do your validation !

}
```

Use regex only when is needed.